# Urls/Array to Tree list in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have the following list:

```
[
  {'http://www.example.com/something/index.htm'}, 
  {'http://www.example.com/something/other.htm'},
  {'http://www.example.com/thatthing/about.htm'},
  {'http://www.example.com/something/thisthing/detail.htm'},
]
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
{ 'www.example.com': 
  [ 
    { 'something': 
      [ 
        { 
          'index.htm',
          'other.htm',
          'thisthing':[
             {
               'detail.htm'
             }
          ]
        }            
      ]
    },
    { 'thatthing': 
      [ 
        { 
          'about.htm'
        }            
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I know that is is a recursive loop that needs to get this done but I can't seem to get it right. I found examples in C#, python and others languages but none in JS.

I need to get a tree list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you :

```js
let data = [
  'http://www.example.com/something/index.htm', 
  'http://www.example.com/something/other.htm',
  'http://www.example.com/thatthing/about.htm',
  'http://www.example.com/something/thisthing/detail.htm'
];

function map(data) {
  let map = [];
  data.forEach(e => merge(map, split(e)));
  return map;
}

function split(href) {
  let parser = document.createElement('a');
  parser.href = href;
  let split = [];
  split.push(parser.hostname);
  parser.pathname.split('/')
    .filter(e => e.length > 0)
    .forEach(e => split.push(e));
  return split;
}

function merge(map, split) {
  let e = split[0];
  if (split.length === 1) {
    if (map.indexOf(e) === -1)
      map.push(e);
  } else {
    if (map.length === 0)
      map[0] = {};
    if (typeof map[0] !== 'object')
      map.unshift({});
    if (e in map[0] === false)
      map[0][e] = [];
    merge(map[0][e], split.slice(1));
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(map(data), null, 2));
```

Comment: Alex your suggestion worked with a little change.

function split(href) { 
  let split = []; 
  href.split('/')
    .filter(e => e.length > 0)
    .forEach(e => split.push(e));
  return split;
}

Comment: Depending on your needs, in this case you will keep protocol, port number, url params, and anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this to create a Trie from a list of words.  You could probably adapt it for your purposes:

```js
      const sortLetters =  (string) => {
        // I'm using a space as a key here because it is the only letter that cannot by any definition be construed as a letter constituting a word.
        let obj = {' ': "\n"};

        for (let i = string.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
          const tmp = {};
          tmp[string[i]] = obj;
          obj = tmp;
        }

        return obj;
      }

      const wordMap = {};

      console.time("Build trie");

      allWords.forEach(function(value){_.merge(wordMap, sortLetters(value))});

      console.timeEnd("Build trie");

      console.log(wordMap);
```